# How do I find the alphabetically-first Term remaining in an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need some help with this project I'm currently working on and anyone's input would be valuable. I have no programming experience at all. I've already created an accumulating parameter and looped through the Terms I guess but can't progress further.

Formula `makeMolecular`
You need to create an accumulating parameter for the molecular formula,
loop through the Terms in the old formula,
in each iteration, find the alphabetically-first Term remaining, add that to the molecular formula, and remove it from the old formula,
combine Terms in the molecular formula, if they have the same element.
The procedure you are using is known as Selection Sort. 
Remember that each element must appear in the molecular formula only once, but it may help you to first construct a version that just produces a molecular formula where the elements are in alphabetical order.

*This is my code:*

```
public void makeMolecular()

{
    ArrayList<Term> terms2 = new ArrayList<Term>();
    ArrayList<Term> terms3 = new ArrayList<Term>();

    for (Term s : terms)
    {
       Term r=nextElement();

       if (r == r)
       {

           terms3.add(r);
           terms2.remove(r);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the constructor if you need it:

```
public Formula(String s)

{
  terms = new ArrayList<>();
  String termstart = s;

  for (int i = s.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      if((Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))) //if character is uppercase at i, starts at i
      {
          terms.add(0, new Term(termstart.substring(i)));
          termstart = s.substring(0, i); 

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: can you show input and expected output?

Comment: Do you think `(r == r)` should ever evaluate to anything other than `true`?

Comment: Yeah because I'm just saying one element is the same as another, i'm not comparing the two, how do I do this? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: What do you mean by input and expected output? Also if the error message is any help, this is what I get:   o2o has 1 component, expected 2 @Whitefret

Comment: "one element is the same as another" is quite different from `(r == r)`, which compares `r` to *itself*.

Comment: Oh okay so that's no good, so should I be declaring another variable and maybe comparing r to it? @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

so, you want to extract from a formula all the atoms used, with no repetition, then use insertion sort to alphabetically sort them

```
public static List<Character> getAtoms(String formula) {
    final List<Character> atoms = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i=0, imax=formula.length(); i<imax; i++)
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(formula.charAt(i))) {
            final Character o = Character.toUpperCase(formula.charAt(i));
            if (!atoms.contains(o))
                atoms.add(o);
        }

    return atoms;
}

public static List<Character> getSortedAtoms(String formula) {

    final List<Character> original = getAtoms(formula);

    final List<Character> sorted = new ArrayList<Character>();
    if (original.size() == 0)
        return sorted;

    final int size = original.size();

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {

        Character best = original.get(i);

        for (int k=i+1; k<size; k++)
            if (original.get(k) < best)
                best = original.get(k);

        sorted.add(best);           
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

these should point you to the right direction.

If you need to convert from/to String/List, use something along the lines of:

```
public static List<Character> stringToList(String text) {
    final List<Character> theList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i=0, imax=text.length(); i<imax; i++)
        theList.add(text.charAt(i));

    return theList;
}

public static String listToString(List<Character> x) {
    String theString = "";

    for (Character c : x)
        theString += c;

    return theString;
}
```